# Computing tow columns with elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

In my example, there are two columns, one is querytime and another one is recordsSize, now I want to get   the max value of querytime/recordsSize with elasticsearch aggregation, How do I get the result? Could someone help me? I'm looking forward to your reply.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: What is a "max value of querytime/recordSize"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Hi Andrei, Sorry for my delay. The data looks like this: [{"querytime":342,"recordsSize":10000},
{"querytime":152,"recordsSize":500},
{"querytime":12,"recordsSize":16},
{"querytime":55,"recordsSize":124}] . For each row querytime/recordSize means the cost time of per records. Now I want to get the max cost time of per records. Thank you for your reply

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. From that data you provided, what should be the result?

Comment: Also, it would be good if you could post your mapping.

Comment: Let me use SQL describe this : SELECT MAX(querytime/recordsSize) FROM DUAL. I want to get a result like this, sorry for my bad English

Comment: I understand now what you want, but I asked for the mapping of that index. Can you post that? You say the data is like `[{"querytime":342,"recordsSize":10000}, {"querytime":152,"recordsSize":500}, {"querytime":12,"recordsSize":16}, {"querytime":55,"recordsSize":124}]`. This seems to be an array of values, how do they look like in the index mapping?

Comment: Actually, My work is to query from an elasticsearch system, which only provide a GUI webpage to me, I don't know the structures of the data. And I want to get the expected result using java API, I can easily get the max "querytime" using code : .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.max(:queryTimeAvg").field("queryTime")), but it’s very hard to me to get the result of ""max value of querytime/recordSize"

Answer (score 0):

You need a query like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "max_time_per_records": {
      "max": {
        "script": "doc['querytime'].value/doc['recordsSize'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, instead of a max for a `field`, you do a max for a `script`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to do it with java API?

Comment: Look at this for sripted metric agg: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-aggs.html#java-aggs-metrics-scripted-metric